# Unable to determine why I recieve a 404 from Challonge API

Tags: php, curl, simplexml

I am working on an Ubuntu server attempting to use the PHP wrapper for the Challonge API. I am only able to get 404 error codes back. I have been debugging the wrapper to see where everything goes wrong. Following are some of my observations.

My main PHP looks like this

```
include('challonge.class.php');

$c = new ChallongeAPI(API_Key); //I have tried this with just my key, as well as in '' and ""

$t = $c->getTournaments();
echo $c->status_code; //This should echo out 200 if it all works correctly
```

The above code was yielding nothing, so I delved into challonge.class.php (the wrapper) to see if I could find what was going wrong. I discovered that status_code would be 404 before a switch statement would print errors, but I never saw any errors. Here is the segment of code where I have decided the problem is

```
$curl_result = curl_exec($curl_handle);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl_handle);
$this->status_code = (int) $info['http_code']; //status_code is 404 here

$return = false;
if ($curl_result === false) { 
  // CURL Failed
  $this->errors[] = curl_error($curl_handle);
} else {
  switch ($this->status_code) {
    case 401: // Bad API Key
    case 422: // Validation errors
    case 404: // Not found/Not in scope of account
      //Everything is good here
      $return = $this->result = new SimpleXMLElement($curl_result);
      //Everything went wrong; cannot echo anything
      foreach($return->error as $error) {
        $this->errors[] = $error;
      }
      $return = false;
      break;
      ...
```

To me, this means that `new SimpleXMLElement($curl_result);` is causing the problem. I do not however know how to find out why. To my knowledge, SimpleXML is installed just fine regardless of why I am getting a 404. I am at a loss for what is going on here or what mistakes I am making.

## Update:

I have solved this problem myself. The reason creating a SimpleXMLElement would throw an error is because Challonge was giving me a 404 error page instead of an xml response. This is due to the PHP wrapper for the Challonge API being outdated.

The plugin uses this URL format for sending requests

```
$call_url = "https://challonge.com/api/v1/".$path.'.xml';
```

The API describes the correct URL format for making HTTP requests as

```
$call_url = "https://api.challonge.com/v1/".$path.'.xml';
```

Making this simple change in the wrapper class solves the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem myself. The reason creating a SimpleXMLElement would throw an error is because Challonge was giving me a 404 error page instead of an xml response. This is due to the PHP wrapper for the Challonge API being outdated.

The plugin uses this URL format for sending requests

```
$call_url = "https://challonge.com/api/v1/".$path.'.xml';
```

The API describes the correct URL format for making HTTP requests as

```
$call_url = "https://api.challonge.com/v1/".$path.'.xml';
```

Making this simple change in the wrapper class solves the problem